# How to manually synchronize MS Wireless Mouse

Tags: wireless-mouse

I bought this Microsoft Wireless Mouses 5000 two times some time ago.

Now - today - it happened, that I got the wrong (bluetooth) transceiver with me. It's theoretically the same as the one from the other mouse, but it's not synchronized with this mouse.

It's called Microsoft 2.4 GHz Transceiver v7.0.

Does anybody know, how to manually synchronize that mouse and transceiver? Or maybe there's just no way to do so?

Comment: Voted to close as off topic, you may have better luck at [su].

Comment: Note that this mouse uses a proprietary 2.4GHz protocol, NOT bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks both. Didn't know of Super User before.